# What's the correct way of defining the use of square root symbol?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

That sounds like a simple question but in my head it is not.

Here's the thing. For real numbers, it's been defined for us since elementary school that, for $a,n\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\geq 0$:

$$\sqrt[2]{a} = n\Leftrightarrow a = n^2.$$

We also learn that $\sqrt[2]{a}$ is a non-negative number. So, $\sqrt[2]{4} = 2$, not $\pm 2$ ($2$ and $-2$ are the square roots of $4$). That'd mean that $\sqrt[2]{a}$ doesn't denote the square roots of $a$, only the positive square root.

Then, when we introduce complex numbers, we learn that for a complex number $z = \rho\cdot(\cos\theta + i\sin \theta$), by De Moivre's formula:

$$\sqrt[n]{z} = \sqrt[n]{\rho}\left(\cos\frac{\varphi + 2k\pi}{n} + i\sin\frac{\varphi + 2k\pi}{n}\right)\text{, $k$ varying over the integer values from $0$ to $n − 1$.}$$

Now, here comes the problem to me.

Since $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$, every real number is also a complex number, right? In fact, real numbers are complex numbers with $\varphi = K\pi$, $K\in\mathbb{Z}$. But then, if for example I plug $\rho = 4$ with $\varphi = 0$, we get $z = 4$. Then, according to De Moivre's law (assuming $n = 2$):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt[2]{z} &= \sqrt[2]{\rho}\left(\cos\frac{\varphi + 2k\pi}{2} + i\sin\frac{\varphi + 2k\pi}
{2}\right)\\
\sqrt[2]{4} &= \sqrt[2]{4}\left(\cos\frac{0 + 2k\pi}{2} + i\sin\frac{0 + 2k\pi}
{2}\right)\\
\sqrt[2]{4} &= 2\left(\cos k\pi + i\sin k\pi\right)\\
\end{align*}

Thus, for $k = 0$ we get $\sqrt[2]{4} = 2$ and for $k = 1$ we get $\sqrt[2]{4} = -2$.

But since $4$ is also a real number, shouldn't the definition I've gave at the beginning be also previewing the negative answer? Thing is, the way I see, it doesn't.

So, assuming we're dealing only with real numbers, $\sqrt[2]{4}$ has only one answer. But if we're dealing with complex numbers context, $\sqrt[2]{4}$ has two? So, $\sqrt[2]{x}$ symbol has an ambiguity only solved knowing the set we're dealing with? 
I'd really appreciate some light here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to read [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536235/what-are-the-branches-of-the-square-root-function), and also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864666/complex-modulus-and-square-root?rq=1)

Comment: The idea that $\sqrt{n^2}=|n|$ for reals is a custom, not a mathematical truth.  Square root is intrinsically a two valued function.

Comment: Hmmm that didn't help me fight this ambiguity (probably for lack of links for me).

Comment: So, did anyone find a way of explaining this?

Answer (score 2):

So, $\sqrt4=\pm2$, however, we like $\sqrt4=2$ better (mostly for the purpose of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ to be a function) hence, we refer to it as the *Principal root* of 4. After that little by little we drop the word *Principle* and that is why  $\sqrt4$ is considered to be $+2$.
If we enter in the WolframAlpha we can see both positive and Negative roots are the outcomes.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=root+of+4