# Is the de Moivre's formula only intended to be used for unknown values of the input $z$, but not to fixed values of $z$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, radicals, radical-equations

This question is related to:
[What's the correct way of defining the use of square root symbol?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660719/whats-the-correct-way-of-defining-the-use-of-square-root-symbol)

As far as I know, the radical symbol $\sqrt{}$ only denotes the principal square root, even in the complex field. So $\sqrt{-4}$ should only be equal to $2i$ and not to $-2i$, because $-2i$ is the secondary square root $-\sqrt{-4}$. However, if we use $-4$ in the De Moivre's formula, we can get both answers.

In the same way, putting $4$ in that formula brings the two answers $2$ and $-2$, so the same expression $\sqrt{4}$  could behave differently depending on the field in which we are working.

But I thought that maybe the mistake comes because de Moivre's formula is not intended to be used for fixed values of $z$, but to find the solutions of $z^n = Expression$.

This in the same sense that in reals the equation $\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{25}$ (that comes from $x^2 = 25$) has multiple solutions because in that case we are asking for the inputs of the function $\sqrt{x^2}$ that provide the given output, while in the case of $\sqrt{5^2} = x$ the solution is only one because we already have the input and we are asking for the output.

Thus, the use of de Moivre's formula for $\sqrt[2]{z}$ could be for $z$ unknown, similar to the case of $\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: de Moivre's formula doesn't have a square-root symbol in it. What _exactly_ do you mean by "use -4 in the de Moivre's formula"?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan With "using $-4$" I meant evaluating $z$ in $-4$ in the formula. Now, if that formula does not have a radical symbol (not only square root symbol but not a radical in general) and rather it is expressed as $z^n = r ....$, then there is no confusion. But I have seen it expressed as $\sqrt[n]{z} = \sqrt[n]{r} ...$

Comment: What, something like "${\root n\of{re^{i\theta}}={\root n\of r}e^{i(\theta+2k\pi)/n}}$"? Well, in that case whoever wrote it that way _isn't_ using the convention that the radical symbol indicates a particular root.

Comment: Anyway: I don't know what it _could mean_ to say that de Moivre's formula "is not intended to be used for fixed values of $z$". It's a theorem; it doesn't care how you use it.